# How to handle bean dependencies of object(s) returned by Factory Method

Tags: java, spring

I am having a hard time figuring this out, I'll first mention the class structure:

- CarDealer
- CarFactory
- Car (Interface)
- BlueCar (Impl of Car)
- RedCar (Impl of Car)
- Tire

The CarFactory class has a factory method which returns a Car. In a Spring XML file (test-spring.xml) the bean definition looks like this:

```
<bean id="carDealer" class="...CarDealer>
    <property name="car" ref="car"/>
</bean>
<bean id="carFactory" class="...CarFactory" />
<bean id="car" factory-bean="carFactory" factory-method="createCar" />

<bean id="tire" class="...Tire" />
```

The factory will return either a RedCar or BlueCar, the calling code doesn't know which one. However let's say for this example, it returns the RedCar.

In a Test Class, in which I am testing the RedCar, it is setup like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-spring.xml" })
public class RedCarTest {

    @Autowired
    Car redCar;
```

In the RedCar class it has a property of Tire:

```
public RedCar implements Car {
    @AutoWired
    private Tire tire;
}
```

In the test example this works fine the redCar returned from the factory is initialized with it's dependency Tire initialized as well. The issue is when I try to run this from my app server.

In the application code the CarDealer class has a reference to a Car:

```
public CarDealer {
    private Car redCar;
}
```

When this code is invoked, the CarDealer is created (by spring) and the Car (by spring) is created, however the Tire property of the Car is null. I don't understand why under the test code the Tire property is getting created, however in the application it's not. Hopefully this is a clearer question than what was previously presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the factory returns a Car ("RedCar"), how can I ensure that the dependent property is initialized.

`@Autowired` does not work because your factory class is instantiating the bean itself, Spring can only autowire dependencies (and act on annotations) when it is creating the bean.

The simplest way to make sure that the object returned by your factory has all of it's properties set would be to set all of the properties in your factory class/method.

So practically speaking, the factory could have a `SomeRedProperty` field for the purposes of passing it to the `RedCar`s that it creates.

Comment: why use an Aspect to enrich an object returned by your factory? That aspect likely only applies to that one factory, making it a bit confusing. Aspects should be used for adding functionality to multiple classes

Comment: And that's what I mean, with aspects @Autowired works in all objects, even the ones created using `new` anywhere in the code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using *@Resource(name="SomeRedProperty")* instead of *@Autowired*?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @matt b that ensuring all properties are set could be done within the factory itself, by you. However, if you do want Spring to manage the Blue and Red Car instances' dependencies you can follow these steps:

1. Your factory will have to implement Spring's `BeanFactoryAware' interface. Once you implement the method from the interface, Spring will provide the class access to the bean factory that created it. Which is basically your application context.
2. Wire up your Red and Blue cars in the context. (Doesn't matter if they are in the same file as the factory or not, as long as all xmls are loaded into context). Make sure the Red and Blue car beans are marked to have scope of 'prototype' if you want each invocation of the factory method to provide a new fully injected instance.
3. In your factory class, implement `setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory)`, simply save a reference to the bean factory.
4. In your factory's `createCar` method, once you've decided which car you want to return, look up the appropriate bean from the bean factory and return to caller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: in the example in your comment, you are asking spring to autowire a property.. the instance of the RedCarTest is being created by Spring (@RunWith) and the instance to be injected is also created by spring. So injection is possible.

Comment: In the real application (JEE app, spring context defined in web.xml) it is under spring as well. For example I have another spring Bean (we'll call it CarDealer) which has a property Car (which maps to the bean id='Car' from above), Car which in this case would be redCar returned from the factory call has the dependency someRedProperty (also a bean). It seems like it would work as all of them "should" be apart of spring. I don't understand why in the test code it works but not in the real application.

Comment: Are you talking about a different issue now? Maybe you should start another question and post the relevant code there.

Comment: It's the same issue just expanded from the original post, I don't post here much so I didn't want too put so much detail here but perhaps I'll edit the question to try and make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: I've expanded the question so hopefully the issue is clearer.

Comment: add the contents of your test-config.xml and carfactory class to your question.